# Issue with join in Teradata

Tags: teradata, join

I have a very strange problem when I do the following join on two different tables in Teradata. It does not return any results, indicating that there is no common value between table_A and table_B.

```
SELECT
*
FROM 
table_A a JOIN table_B b ON a.id = b.id;
```

<>

```
0 rows returned
```

However when I run the following two queries, I do get results indicating that the id column in both the tables has at least one row with 'John'.

```
SELECT
id
FROM table_A
WHERE
id = 'John';
```

<>

```
 1 row returned

SELECT
id
FROM table_B
WHERE
id = 'John';
```

<>

```
1 row returned
```

The data type for all the columns in table_A and table_B is null

Comment: Can you try: `ON trim(a.id) = trim(b.id);` to insure there is not any white space hanging out in there? Also, you say the data type is NULL for these fields? I don't believe you can have a NULL data type. Is it a Char() or VARCHAR() for the `id` fields?

Comment: And what is returned by the individual queries? What's the datatype of id?

Comment: What is returned when you switch to a FULL OUTER JOIN?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using  the below approach :

```
ON trim(UPPER(table_A.id)) = trim(UPPER(table_B.id))
```